# Unspecified Error when trying to ExecuteReader on SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I had implemented a database storage on my app for Windows Mobile 6.5 using SQL Server CE.

Had managed to install the SQL Server CE CAB file on the device (Motorola MC65).

Managed to create database file, and create tables. Insert also can be executed.

However when I try to run `ExecuteReader()` to read records, I hit the following error:

> Error Code: 80004005
>   Message   : Unspecified error
>   Minor Err.: 25534
>   Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider

No idea why this is happening. Since `insert` can be executed I thought this should not be a connection or privilege issue.

The reading code is as below:

```
openConnection();
SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME FROM GROUP_INFO ORDER BY NAME ";

SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
      string groupName = reader.GetString(0);
      listGroup.Add(groupName);
}
```

The exception is thrown on the line where `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is executing.

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Beside surrounding the executeReader by try/catch, add an ; at the end of each sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement proper error handling for SqlCeExceptions! The error is documented here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172350(v=sql.110).aspx

Large objects (ntext and image) cannot be used in ORDER BY clauses.

Maybe you should redefine the column as nvarchar(4000) (it is currently ntext), or rephrase the query using:

```
 ORDER BY CAST(Name as nvarchar(4000))
```

But this will cause a table scan